# Software for capturing still image snapshots from video input

Tags: video-capture

What software is available that will let me watch video from a USB video capture device at full PAL/NTSC resolution and capture a still image at a button press?

More info:  I'm using a [KaiserBaas USB capture device](http://www.kaiserbaas.com/kaiser-baas-product-page/converters/video-to-dvd-maker), and want to capture screen shots from a PS2 connected to it. I'd like to play the game at the full PS2 resolution and capture certain scenes.

The device has a one-touch snapshot button on it, but I can't seem to make it work and there's no mention of it anywhere in the documentation.  The device works and the video appears in Power Producer (the included software), but I think it previews it smaller than the full resolution.  I could print screen it, but having to crop will be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Linux, Windows or Mac OS X? I use a program called [Jing](http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) by TechSmith. It is available for Windows and Mac OS X. I believe this may be what you're looking for. It allows you to screen-cap by Application window, selective windows inside an application, the entire full res of your monitor and even selecting your own area of the screen to capture. Give it a try.

Comment: Jing is for screen capture of the PC screen.  I want to capture directly from a video capture device connected to my PC.  Also, I don't want to capture video - just stills from that video capture device. Also, I want them at the full PAL/NTSC resolution - if I just print+screen or use some other screen capture tool I'll just get the smaller preview that the included software shows.

Comment: If you're on OS X, it can already do this. ⇧⌘3 captures the whole screen, and ⇧⌘4 captures an area (hit Space to switch to window capture--including the shadow!)